# how to integration Ziggeo Sdk to Ionic App

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ziggeo-api, ziggeo-sdk

I want to integrate the Ziggeo' sdk into my ionic app,I spend 2 day on it but 
I'm not able to integrate  Ziggeo' sdk into my ionic app.
I downlade demo ionic project from github(source:- https://github.com/Ziggeo/ionic2-ziggeo-demo),I can't understated how i can include this to my project?

Comment: Have you tried this steps https://github.com/Ziggeo/ionic2-ziggeo-demo/blob/master/README.md ? 
If you did, on which steps you need help?

Comment: do i need manually installation?,I didn't find any "ionic  install command"?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to manually install the ionic and the dependency itself. Just like the Readme file said, you can use `npm install -g cordova ionic` to install.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite simple.

1. Install the [Ziggeo Client SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ziggeo-client-sdk) via npm.
2. ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="build/ziggeo.css" /> 
   <script src="build/ziggeo.js"></script>
   ```

   Then, you need to specify your API token:

   ```
   <script>
       var ziggeoApp = new ZiggeoApi.V2.Application({
           token: "APPLICATION_TOKEN"
       }); 
   </script>
   ```

   > *Note:* You will get the `Api_token` either through Ziggeo, or you can upload a video and receive one.
3. Now, at last, you can either record or play a video by doing the following:

   ```
   <ziggeorecorder></ziggeorecorder>
   ```

   To embed a player for an existing video, add:

   ```
   <ziggeoplayer ziggeo-video='video-token'></ziggeoplayer>
   ```
4. Finally, if you use Angular in Ionic, I suggest you use the `angular-ziggeo` package from npm. It makes things much simpler.